# AWS dynamoDB scan string set IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, database-scan

I have a data set that I want to scan and filter out.

I want to filter out these two values in my table:

- F7138546-5819-4534-98F8-959A2B8DC06E
- DFG83855-FF86-440D-8CA0-15A2709A58E8

Is it right to enter the two data in attribute.SS? Is there another way for me to achieve this function? Please help me cause I have been thinking about this for a very long time. The criteria should be `or`, that is, the hash key will not be value a or value b rather than neither a nor b.

```
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *objectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];

scanExpression.exclusiveStartKey = self.lastEvaluatedKey;
scanExpression.limit = @20;

attribute.SS = @[@"F7138546-5819-4534-98F8-959A2B8DC06E",@"DFG83855-FF86-440D-8CA0-15A2709A58E8"];

AWSDynamoDBCondition *condition = [AWSDynamoDBCondition new];

condition.attributeValueList = @[attribute];
condition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperatorNE;

scanExpression.scanFilter = @{@"hashKey":condition};

return [[[objectMapper scan:[DDBTableRow class]
                     expression:scanExpression]
```

Thank you for that. Thank you again

Comment: Looks sound to me. Is it not working, or are you just wanting to validate your thoughts?

Comment: The output is not workable. I don't know why. I finally use an instance method to store each of the key separately before showing anything in the table

Comment: All the values in the DB are shown except the values i input in the above.